# Delete record from table in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am working with two tables *Mitigations* and *New Control IDs* in an Access database. The *Mitigations* table has a form. As part of that form, a control *ID* can be added to the *New Control IDs* table. My code for that works fine. I am trying to add the ability to delete a record from the *New Control IDs* table via the *Mitigations* form.

The user will enter a string in *Text55* and after updating that field, the corresponding record in the *New Control IDs* table should be deleted.

Here is the code I have for that:

```vb
Private Sub Text55_AfterUpdate()

'removing record with Archer Control ID from New Control IDs table
Dim dbNewInitiatives As DAO.Database
Dim rstMitigations As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

    Set dbNewInitiatives = CurrentDb
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [New Control IDs] WHERE ([Mitigation ID] = " & Me.[Mitigation ID].Value & ") AND ([Archer Control ID] = '" & Me.[Text55].Value & "') ORDER BY [ID]"
    Set rstMitigations = dbNewInitiatives.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

    Do While Not rstMitigations.EOF
        rstMitigations.Delete
        rstMitigations.MoveNext
    Loop

rstMitigations.Close

Set rstMitigations = Nothing
Set dbNewInitiatives = Nothing

End Sub
```

The above code successfully finds all of the records in *New Control IDs* table that meet the criteria and deletes them. Thank you!

Comment: *something fundamentally wrong*... *I'm having a difficult time figuring out what that is*...can you post any error to precisely figure out issue?

Comment: Perhaps this has nothing to do with your problem, but the code has _End Function_ in the Sub, and it looks like the MsgBox will always be shown whether there is an error or not.  As Parfait already said, you need to post what the actual problem... error codes and descriptions, unexpected behavior, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Consider running a `DELETE` action query using the [Database.Execute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197654.aspx) method without the need of a DAO recordset:

```vb
Set dbNewInitiatives = CurrentDb
strSQL = "DELETE FROM [New Control IDs]" _
           & " WHERE ([Mitigation ID] = " & Me.[Mitigation ID].Value & ")" _
           & " AND ([Control ID] = '" & Me.[Text55].Value & "')"

dbNewInitiatives.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

Comment: I gave this a shot and received Run-time error '3061': Too few parameters. Expected 2.The following line of code was highlighted: dbNewInitiatives.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

Comment: Are those two fields *Mitigation ID* and *Control ID* in the *New Control IDs* table with those exact names? If they do not exist in the table you will receive such an error. I assumed how you wrote it was correct.

Comment: You're right, Control ID had a syntax error, but after fixing that I still get the same run-time error, but Too few parameters. Expected 1. I have triple checked the rest of the names. Would Text55 being an unbound text box have anything to do with it?

Comment: [Text55] needs single apostrophe before and after the quotation marks due to it being a string and not an integer.

Comment: So there you have it. Recall I grabbed exactly as your original `SELECT` query. Only you know your data. String variables do need quote enclosure.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely consider Parfait's answer, but it is always good to understand what the problem was in the first place.  To me it looks like the logic in your loop is probably incorrect.

Unless you provide more detail, I'll first assume that [New Control IDs].[ID] is a unique key on that table.  If that is the case, then you are storing that unique ID in the variable strID but then moving to the next record before actually attempting to delete the record.  In this case, the If statement in the loop will **always be false** since the current record's [ID] would not equal the previous record's [ID] value.

```
...
Do While Not rstMitigations.EOF
    '* This compares the previous row's [ID] with the current row's [ID]  '
    If rstMitigations![ID] = strID Then
        rstMitigations.Delete
...
```

If the [ID] values are *not unique*, then your code would only delete subsequent rows that matched the first in a series of identical [ID] values.  It would leave the first row of each unique [ID] value untouched (i.e. not deleted). If there is only one of a particular [ID] value, that row will never be deleted.  Is that what you want?

Notice that Parfait's action query will delete all of the same records returned by your SELECT query.  Just for the record, to accomplish this with the recordset, just simplify it to be

```
....
Set dbNewInitiatives = CurrentDb
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [New Control IDs] WHERE ([Mitigation ID] = " _
        & Me.[Mitigation ID].Value & ") AND ([Control ID] = " _
        & Me.[Text55].Value & ") ORDER BY [ID]"
Set rstMitigations = dbNewInitiatives.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

Do While Not rstMitigations.EOF
    rstMitigations.Delete
    rstMitigations.MoveNext
Loop
....
```

Comment: [New Control IDs].[ID] is a unique key on that table. I am looking to delete the record from [New Control IDs] where [New Control IDs].[Mitigation ID] and [New Control IDs].[Control ID] match [Mitigations].[Mitigation ID] and [Mitigations].[Text55] respectively. Trying your suggestion above produced the same run-time error that Parfait's suggest did. "Too few parameters. Expected 2."